# Mock mongodb AggregateIterable with expected mock data

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to `MongDB/Java`. I am trying to write a Junit for `AggregateIterable`. Where I want to add some mock data to iterable but not sure how to add the expected mock data. Could you please give me some example or direction how can mock the `AggregateIterable` with expected mock data.

I am trying to write `Junit` or `mock` for below snippet of code -

```
List<Employee> results = getCollection().aggregate(pipeline).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

I tried below but result size is always zero.

```
AggregateIterable<Employee> iterable = Mockito.mock(AggregateIterable.class);
MongoCursor iterator = Mockito.mock(MongoCursor.class);
Employee employee1 = Mockito.mock(Employee.class);
Employee employee2 = Mockito.mock(Employee.class);

when(iterable.iterator()).thenReturn(iterator);
when(iterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true,true,false);
when(iterator.next()).thenReturn(employee1,employee1);
Mockito.doReturn(iterable).when(mongoCollection).aggregate(Mockito.any(ArrayList.class));
```